# Advanced Eloquent relationship with pivot?

Tags: laravel-4, pivot-table, eloquent

I'm building a vehicle maintenance system. Each vehicle has one or more components attached. Each vehicle and component is "owned" by an account. A user may wish to detach a component from a vehicle and place it on the shelf for later re-attachment to the same or another vehicle. The component holds a vehicle_id field so detaching is easy, I just null the vehicle_id field and the component is effectively "shelved".

My difficulty is with finding attachable components to display a list of shelved components that are attachable to a selected vehicle. The vehicle_types_component_types table is a pivot that defines which component types can be attached to which vehicle types. Some component types can be installed on multiple vehicle types and each vehicle type has one or more component types that can be installed.

```
class VehicleType extends Eloquent {
    public function ComponentTypes() { return $this->belongsToMany('ComponentType', 'vehicle_types_component_types')->withTimestamps(); }
}

class Vehicle extends Eloquent {
    public function Account() { return $this->belongsTo('Account', 'account_id'); }
    public function VehicleType() { return $this->belongsTo('VehicleType', 'vehicle_type_id'); }
    public function Components() { return $this->hasMany('Component'); }
}

class ComponentType extends Eloquent {
    public function VehicleTypes() { return $this->belongsToMany('VehicleTypes', 'vehicle_types_component_types')->withTimestamps(); }
    public function Components() { return $this->hasMany('Component'); }
}

class Component extends Eloquent {
    public function Account() { return $this->belongsTo('Account', 'account_id'); }
    public function Vehicle() { return $this->belongsTo('Vehicle', 'vehicle_id'); } // This is null when component is not attached to vehicle
    public function ComponentType() { return $this->belongsTo('ComponentType', 'component_type_id'); }
}
```

So that I'm looking to do is find all components that belong to a specified account_id, and have a null vehicle_id, and where the component's component type is "installable" on the vehicle type as defined in the vehicle_types_component_types pivot table. To top it all off, I also need to exclude certain components by their component type ... where component_type != 'tire', for example.

What I've tried that obviously doesn't work but should demonstrate what I'm trying to do ...

```
public function findAttachable($vehicle_type_id, $account_id)
{
    return Component::with('ComponentType')
        ->where('vehicle_id', null)
        ->where('account_id', $account_id)
        ->where('vehicle_type_component_type.vehicle_type_id', $vehicle_type_id)
        ->where('vehicle_type_component_type.component_type_id', 'components.components_type_id')
        ->where('component_types.type', '!=', 'tire');
}
```

If there was something like a "withPivot" method or something, that would be really cool ...

```
$components = Component::where('vehicle_id', null)
    ->where('account_id', $account_id)
    ->withPivot('component_type_id', $vehicle_type_id);
```

Any help with this would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

## Introduction

Your story was slightly confusing but i think you are trying to do something like this. 
Answer is 3 month's late but since you wanted a more elegant way here it is.

There is actually a method "withPivot" like you suggested. It works just slightly different than you have suggested.

> ->withPivot('field1frompivottable', 'field2frompivottable', 'ect')

See: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

## Example

**Table's:**

Table: vehicle

- id
- name
- type

Table: vehicletype

- id
- name

Table: component

- id
- name
- vehicle

Table: vehicletypecomponentpivottable

- id
- vehicletypeid
- componentid
- installed

**Eloquent Models:**

vehicle model:

```
class Vehicle extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'vehicle';

    public function type() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Vehicletype', 'type');
    }
    public function component() {
        return $this->hasMany('Component', 'vehicle');
    }

}
```

vehicle type model:

```
class Vehicletype extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'vehicletype';

    public function vehicle() {
        return $this->hasMany('Vehicle', 'type');
    }
    public function component() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Component', 'vehicletypecomponentpivottable', 'vehicletypeid', 'componentid')
        ->withPivot('installed');
    }

}
```

component:

```
class Component extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'component';

    public function vehicle() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Vehicle', 'vehicle');
    }
    public function vehicletype() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vehicletype', 'vehicletypecomponentpivottable', 'componentid', 'vehicletypeid')
        ->withPivot('installed');
    }

}
```

**controller functions**

```
public function get_uninstalled_components_that_fit_my_vehicle($vehicletypeid){
    return Vehicletype::find($vehicletypeid)->component()->wherePivot('installed', 0)->get();
}

public function is_component_installed($componentid){
    return Component::find($componentid)->Vehicletype()->pivot->installed;
}
```

## Good luck!

Hope this helps! You can filter on pivot results using `wherePivot` and `orWherePivot`

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution that seems to work. I just wish there was a more elegant way to do this. If there is, please let me know.

```
public function findAttachable($vehicle_type_id, $account_id)
{
    return Component::with('ComponentType')
        ->where('vehicle_id', null)
        ->where('account_id', $account_id)
        ->whereIn('component_type_id', function($query) use ($vehicle_type_id) {
            $query->select('component_type_id')
                ->from('vehicle_types_component_types')
                ->where('vehicle_type_id', $vehicle_type_id);
            })
        ->whereNotIn('component_type_id', function($query) {
            $query->select('id')
                ->from('component_types')
                ->where('type', 'tire');
            })
        ->get();
}
```